# Is there an issue with this recursive combination generation algorithm (Python 3)?

Tags: python, recursion

Trying to generate all possible combinations of values within the list 'looper' to a user-specified maximum character length. To do this, I tried my hand at a recursive algorithm, and produced the below:

```
def generate_combinations(length, num_times, first_time):
    looper = ['1', '2', '3','4']
    if num_times == 0 and first_time:
        word_list = []
        word = ''
    elif num_times == 0:
        word = ''
    elif num_times == length and len(word_list) == 4 ** length:
        return word_list    
    else:
        for letter in looper:
            word += letter
            num_times +=1
            if num_times == length:
                word_list.append(word)
                generate_combinations(length, 0, False)
                
            else:
                generate_combinations(length, (num_times), False)
```

For some reason, it is returning a value of `None` whenever run.

I cannot identify the issue with my code, and, if anyone could, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You forgot the `return` on the recursive calls and in some if conditions.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues Is there a need to include return statements on the recursive calls and all if conditions? The code is designed to return one list of combinations at the end of its run, once all combinations have been generated (len(word_list) == len(looper) ** length), so to me that seems like it could interfere with the correct function of the function.

Comment: Yes. Of course. If the function does not find a return statement it returns `None`. Try it on simpler example.

Comment: Right. But it does return.

Comment: elif num_times == length and len(word_list) == 4 ** length:
        return word_list

Comment: It returns `None`. Is that not the issue?

Comment: Shouldn't that do the trick?

Comment: I will reexamine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, it does if the condition applies otherwise no.

Answer (score 1):

You keep dismissing sound advice -- it's all about the return values of the recursive calls.  You can't change variables in one recursive frame and assume they'll change in others.  And if I understand the underlying problem correctly, you're making it harder than necessary:

```
def generate_combinations(length):
    looper = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

    if length == 1:
        return looper

    word_list = []

    if length == 0:
        return word_list

    for suffix in generate_combinations(length - 1):
        for letter in looper:
            word_list.append(letter + suffix)

    return word_list

print(generate_combinations(3))
```

Let the recursion do the work.

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
['111', '211', '311', '411', '121', '221', '321', '421', '131', '231', '331', '431', '141', '241', '341', '441', '112', '212', '312', '412', '122', '222', '322', '422', '132', '232', '332', '432', '142', '242', '342', '442', '113', '213', '313', '413', '123', '223', '323', '423', '133', '233', '333', '433', '143', '243', '343', '443', '114', '214', '314', '414', '124', '224', '324', '424', '134', '234', '334', '434', '144', '244', '344', '444']
%
```

Answer (score 0):

You are completly ignoring the return of the recursive calls.

Take the following fibonacci example:

```py
def fib(n):
   if n <= 1:
       return n
   else:
       return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Also if there is a condition that never reaches a return statement the function will return `None`. In the example above, if we remove the last return the function will return `None` for all values greater than `1`.

### A quick rundown

```py
>>> fib(1)
1
```

Since `1` is less than or equal to `1`. The function takes the first return.

```py
>>> fib(2)
1
```

`2` is greater that `1` so we must take the second path. Get `fib` of `1` (`2 - 1`) and, `fib` of `0` (`2 - 2`).

Since both calls are recursive, we need to repeat this rundown twice, one for `1` another for `0`. (do that, thats the recursion)

When that is done, get back and add the results. The first result is `1`, the second is `0`. `1 + 0 = 1` return `1`.

Comment: And before anyone comes mocking me. Yes, this is a highly inefficient algorithm.

Comment: However, the algorithm is only intended to return one value of type list (word_list), which contains all generated combinations.

Comment: And this value is returned once all combinations have been generated.

Comment: Calling `fib(10)` returns the tenth fibonacci number. Not any other.

Comment: I've updated the example with a step by step execution of the function. You can do it yourself manually with a paper to keep track of the variables, everytime you find a recursive call, get another piece of paper. (that is how python executes the thing)